# Найти индекс элемента массива

Tags: javascript

Как найти индекс элемента массива где найден объект `{active: true}`
В массиве `[null, null, {active: true}]`

```
activeState.findIndex((item) => item === {active:true})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activeState.findIndex((item) => item&&item.active === true)
```

Comment: интересно, зачем сравнение на булево булевого свойства?)

Comment: item && item.active интересная конструкция. на true надо искать так что Лев правильно сделал

Comment: activeState.findIndex((item) => item&&item.active) ну можно и так, просто чтобы понятней было написал. Отметь ответ как правильный если все норм @svitalik1999gmailcom

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom а что, есть третье состояние помимо активный и неактывный? Зависший между миров?)))

Comment: @Алексей, у свойства может быть truthy значение небулевого типа (и это может расцениваться ложным срабатыванием), тогда как строгая проверка гарантирует буквальное соответствие значению `true`.

Comment: @yar85 зачем для однозначно булевого типа ставить не true/false?))

Comment: @Алексей, незачем, но тут однозначность отсутствует (она логически отрицается в первую очередь возникновением задачи с обозначенными условиями, и во вторую - динамической типизацией JS).

Comment: @yar85 в задаче указан поиск по значению в виде объекта. Про то, что там может быть что-то отличное от булевого значения не сказано... А динамическая типизация языка вообще не причём. Это чистая логика и организованность разработчика, а не что-то, зависимое от типизации языка. userIsAdmin  не должна возвращать null, 1/0, "true" (строка), " false " (строка) и прочей чепухи, кроме как четкого конкретного булева, будь это хоть трижды динамически типизированным языком.

Comment: @Алексей, _«в задаче указан поиск по значению в виде объекта»_ - значит надо сделать вывод что других значений в массиве быть не может, и/или что в js-объектах не может быть ничего, кроме `action: true`  Браво чистой логике, ибо она чиста и логична!

Answer (score 1):

- В случае поиска элемента массива **по свойству `active` имеющему значение `true`** (современный синтаксис, ES11+):

```js
const activeState = [null, null, { active: true }];
console.log(
  activeState.findIndex(item => item?.active === true)
);
```

---

- В случае поиска элемента массива **буквального соответствующего объекту**:

```js
const activeState = [null, null, { active: true }],
      search = JSON.stringify({ active: true });
console.log(
  activeState.findIndex(item => JSON.stringify(item) === search)
);
```

*// этот способ только для сериализуемых объектов, и при соблюдении порядка перечисления их свойств (что не всегда выполняется) - для прочих случаев, нужно будет написать функцию-компаратор с перебором всех собственных свойств обоих объектов*